# Finding arithmetic mean of numbers asked in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, loops, prompt

What I need to achieve are the following conditions:

1. a script asks for a number (in a prompt) between 1 and 100 in an infinite loop
2. if a user enters NaN, empty string or a number off the range it asks for a number again
3. if a user presses cancel, display an alert with a number of digits entered and their arithmetic mean
4. i can't use an array!

here's what I have, and I understand that I'm missing some key logic in here, any suggestions?

```
  while (true) {
    var userInput = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 100:");
    var num = parseInt(userInput, 10);
    if (num >= 1 && num <= 100) {
      var nums = 0;
      nums += num;
      var counter = 0;
      counter++;
    } else if (userInpuft === null) {
      alert(nums / counter);
      alert(counter);
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why can't you use an array? That would seem to be the most sensible course of action

Comment: Your code is already fine. Just bring `var nums` and `var counter` outside the loop so they don't get reset on each iteration.

Comment: Also a typo in `userInpuft`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean of a set of numbers can be calculated incrementally, without having to save all the numbers anywhere. All you need is the previous mean and the count of numbers that have been entered.

Consider the formula `mean = total/count`. If you know `mean` and `count`, you can invert the equation to `total = mean * count`.

When you get a new number, the count goes up by 1, and the new number is added to the total. So the formula is `mean = (mean * (count - 1) + new_number)/count`.

```js
let count = 0;
let mean = 0;
while (true) {
  let input = prompt("Enter a number");
  if (input === null) {
    break;
  }
  new_number = parseFloat(input);
  if (!isNaN(new_number) && new_number >= 1 && new_number <= 100) {
    count++;
    mean = (mean * (count - 1) + new_number) / count;
    alert(`Count = ${count}, Mean = ${mean}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: but it has to prompt for a number again, not alert the user

Comment: It does prompt again, after alerting the user.

Comment: You can take that out if you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use an array, I suppose an alternative would be to store the values in an object:

```js
let counter = 0;
const nums = {};
while (true) {
  var userInput = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 100:");
  var num = parseInt(userInput, 10);
  if (!(num >= 1 && num <= 100)) {
    // Invalid:
    continue;
  }
  nums[counter] = num;
  counter++;
  const allNumsSoFar = Object.values(nums);
  const mean = allNumsSoFar.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / allNumsSoFar.length;
  alert('Mean: ' + mean);
}
```

If that's not allowed either, you can keep track of the sum and the number of numbers entered so far:

```js
let numCount = 0;
let sumSoFar = 0;
while (true) {
  var userInput = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 100:");
  var num = parseInt(userInput, 10);
  if (!(num >= 1 && num <= 100)) {
    // Invalid:
    continue;
  }
  numCount++;
  sumSoFar += num;
  const mean = sumSoFar / numCount;
  alert('Mean: ' + mean);
}
```

You might consider using a proper modal instead of `prompt`, since `prompt` is very user-unfriendly:

```js
let numCount = 0;
let sumSoFar = 0;
const processNum = () => {
  var num = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  if (!(num >= 1 && num <= 100)) {
    // Invalid:
    return;
  }
  numCount++;
  sumSoFar += num;
  const mean = sumSoFar / numCount;
  output.textContent = 'Mean: ' + mean;
};
```

```html
<div>Enter a number between 1 and 100:</div>
<input id="input"><button onclick="processNum()">submut</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```